# Maven class polution?

Tags: maven

I noticed that some common files such as settings.xml are stored in users .m2 folder. I'm new to maven and don't follow how to avoid several projects sharing the same file. Also does this directory just keep growing/building using different versions of jars? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You can override global settings. But yes: your local repo will continue to grow--that's what caches do; they cache, and the more things you use, the more it'll cache.

Comment: First the `settings.xml` should be in `$USERHOME/.m2/settings.xml` cause it could/should contain credentials for accessing repositories ...and usually encrypted...and as already mentioned you can change the location of the local cache if you like...The directory which contains the cache is the `$USERHOME/.m2/repository` ..which will grow over the time...if it becomes to large in your opinion you can delete it this means dependencies needed to be downloaded from remote repositories...Apart from that it's organized based on groupId/artifactId/Versions ..so I don't see a "Polution" there...